# In python I need to remove 1st letter

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a large dataframe as below:

df1 (sample data)

```
a      name       keywords
1      ramesh     rrahul,rapple
2      venkat     rtemple
3      rajesh     rcake,rphone,rmaths
4      lamda      rcon
5      feast      rcamera,rtab
```

I want to remove letter `r` which occurs **at the beginning of each word** in strings which consist of comma-separated words. The output should be as below:

```
a      name       keywords
1      ramesh     rahul,apple
2      venkat     temple
3      rajesh     cake,phone,maths
4      lamda      con
5      feast      camera,tab
```

Comment: how are you reading in the data? is that a pandas dataframe? a csv file? what have you tried so far?

Comment: it is a pandas dataframe

Comment: @RahulVarma - There are always `r` in first place for each word? Or is possible sometimes not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with `regex` pattern as:

```
import re
pat = re.compile(r'^r|(?<=,)[r]')
df['keywords'] = df.keywords.str.replace(pat,'')
```

Or:

```
df['keywords'] = df.keywords.str.replace(r'^r|(?<=,)[r]','')
```

---

```
print(df)
   a    name          keywords
0  1  ramesh       rahul,apple
1  2  venkat            temple
2  3  rajesh  cake,phone,maths
3  4   lamda               con
4  5   feast        camera,tab
```

**Explanation to regex :**

1. `^r` checks whether there is `r` at the start of string.
2. `(?<=,)[r]` check whether there is `r` after every `,`

The list comprehension method by [`jezrael`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53206949/8320861) is faster than `str.replace`, whereas if you have null/ NaN values then `str.replace` can take care of those with out hustle.

Answer (score 6):

Use nested list comprehension with `join` and `split`:

*Notice*:

*Assuming no null/ NaNs values.*

```
df['keywords'] = [','.join(y[1:] for y in x.split(',')) for x in df['keywords']]
print (df)
   a    name          keywords
0  1  ramesh       rahul,apple
1  2  venkat            temple
2  3  rajesh  cake,phone,maths
3  4   lamda               con
4  5   feast        camera,tab
```

If possible sometimes not exist first letter with `r` is possible a bit change solution with `if-else`:

```
print (df)
   a    name             keywords
0  1  ramesh            aa,rapple
1  2  venkat              rtemple
2  3  rajesh  rcake,rphone,rmaths
3  4   lamda                 rcon
4  5   feast         rcamera,rtab

df['keywords'] = [','.join(y[1:] if y[0] == 'r' 
                                 else y 
                                 for y in x.split(',')) for x in df['keywords']]
print (df)
   a    name          keywords
0  1  ramesh          aa,apple
1  2  venkat            temple
2  3  rajesh  cake,phone,maths
3  4   lamda               con
4  5   feast        camera,tab
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df["keywords"] = df["keywords"].apply(lambda x: ",".join([w[1:] if w[0] == "r" else w for w in x.split(",")]) )
df

a   name    keywords
1   ramesh  rahul,apple
2   venkat  temple
3   rajesh  cake,phone,maths
4   lamda   con
5   feast   camera,tab
```